# Is Plato's ideal world comparable to heaven?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, plato, idea

Plato thought there was an ideal world where ideas live. Independently of people. These ideas throw a shadow on the material world we live in. By examining this material world we can get knowledge of the world of ideas. But this knowledge will never be perfect. We can make a 3D cube from stone or we can construct an image of it in the head but it will still be a reflection or shadow. Math gets close but still it doesn't give the idea itself. Maybe Plato had a different view regarding the last (his cubes, tetraheders, dodecaeders, etc. are thought by him to be perfect "Platonc" objects corresponding to how the ideal world looks like). I am not sure. Of course there are many more objects thinkable than his Platonic objects.

Is his ideal world comparable to the concept of heaven? Of course the question is what I mean by comparable. Well, both offer an ideal world. An idealized version of reality. In heaven there is no wordly suffering, for example. In the ideal world of Plato the ideas don't suffer from human contamination. What are the differences? Can his ideal world be compared with heaven in the first place?

Comment: I would appreciate if the downvoter explained. I really don't give a damned about downviting as long as explained. I can help it to have interesting questions...

Comment: Imean; just voting down because it is me who asked (which I susoect( is just childish. I might be paranoid but I dont think I am. Someone voted 10 of my question down in a row last night.

Comment: What do you mean by "comparable"? Plato's world was static and unchanging, Heaven is full of living souls. On the other hand they are both perfect and eternal. Please clarify your criteria for comparison.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Comparable insofar the elements and Nature of the worlds and their relation to the world we live in is concerned. In my answer I refer to them. The elements of heaven are very different from the elements of the Platonic world.

Comment: The OP's quick answer to their own question, and their subsequent comments, shows that this question is about pushing a personal philosophy. I am voting to close it.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Who is pushing? You are pushing. To close it. Everybody is free to not agree. This is an open discussion. Pushing...

Comment: The comment above is based on nothing. Their comment to close is based on the assumption I push. Why do they think? I just answer my own question and invite others to answer too. In reaction to me "pushing".

Comment: I hesitate over this question. I can understand from the comments why there is objection to it but I prefer to let it run. I am clearer about what the Platonic world of Forms (if it existed) would be like than I am about Heaven (if it exists). Yet there may be some value in conceptually juxtaposing the two - it's certainly a novel association nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Heaven is an ideal (and eternal) place too. Life on Earth is just a shadow from life in heaven. Just as the ideas of Plato are. We can approximate heaven on Earth as we can approximate the ideas in the ideal world (the world of ideas). There is a one to one correspondence between the world on Earth and the ideal world or the heavenly world. All good, just, or nice experiences are present in heaven, like all ideas (especially the mathematical ones and of these especially the Platonic geometrical objects) are present in the world of ideas. An idea can be approximated by constructing it's physical appearance. Like we can approximate heavenly elements.

There are differences though. Plato's world is a unique world. Heaven though can't exist without hell. Both worlds coexist. In one you experience only suffering  [like experiencing endless repetition of things as is described in the book "Het Leven van een Dag" (the life of one day)].

The elements of both worlds clearly differ too. The world of ideas that Plato envisioned contains mathematical ones only. Heaven includes these also and on top of it a considerable portion of the wordly world (only in a heavenly way).

Apart from both being eternal, both having an existence outside the worldly domain, and both having elements (which differ in Nature though), the Platonic world will never be entered by people. I think this is the biggest difference. In heaven there could be Platonic ideas present. So the Platonic world is a sub world of the heavenly world but contrary to heaven it cannot be entered. Elements of both though can be experienced on Earth but in an approximated way.

Comment: You answer your own question the same day you post it. This strikes me as very odd, it sseems almost as if you posted the question just so you could post your answer. Can you explain why?

Comment: @GuyInchbald Well, this is an anwer and question format site. I had already an idea about the answer (yes they can). It is a good philosophical tradition to use the dialogue.

Comment: OK, so you did it to peddle your own answer, not to ask others to help you out.

Comment: @GuyInchbald I have not accepted my own answer.

Comment: No, it is not....

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why not?

Comment: See [Intelligible realm and separation of the Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_forms#Intelligible_realm_and_separation_of_the_Forms): "Plato often invokes, poetic language to illustrate the mode in which the Forms are said to exist. Near the end of the Phaedo, for example, Plato describes the world of Forms as a pristine region of the physical universe located above the surface of the Earth (Phd. 109a-111c). In the Phaedrus the Forms are in a "place beyond heaven" (Phdr. 247c ff); and in the Republic. the sensible world is contrasted with the intelligible realm."

Comment: It would be a mistake to take Plato's imagery as positing the intelligible world as a literal physical space apart from this one. Plato emphasizes that the Forms are not beings that extend in space (or time), but subsist apart from any physical space whatsoever.Thus we read in the Symposium of the Form of Beauty: "It is not anywhere in another thing, as in an animal, or in earth, or in heaven, or in anything else, but itself by itself with itself.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA How could plato have known about heaven? If so, heaven is as detached from earth as his world of forms. The very fact that he sees heaven as a different world makes that they can be compared.

Comment: Heaven Is A Award to People Behaving Good (with the same Material Body), Ideal Plato World Is Giving The Imagination Their Own Independent World. I Thingk They Are Different Sustantly. The Context is Different, The Goal is Different, Only That Both Are Fiction / Mithical Thoughts Is the Same. Althought christianist take some ideas from platos and aristotle they change a lot the meaning and use it convently as it was the status quo of logical thinking.